# Power BI scheduled update to AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, powerbi, amazon-rds, onpremises-gateway

Having a MariaDB database up in AWS RDS hosted through an EC2 instance, I still can't get Power BI to agree on scheduling updates. Is there anything I have missed?

- I have installed an on-premises data gateway on the EC2 instance
- I have installed an ODBC driver for the MariaDB database (and the DSN successfully connects to the RDS, successfully being able to list database tables etc)

Error message that appears on Power BI:

- Unable to connect to the datasource undefined

Power BI can find the Gateway, but I can't go any further from there.

MariaDB and the EC2 instance are rolling on the same VPC, and the security group has (for now) open on all IPV4 for all port ranges.

Answer (score 0):

After deploying the Dataset you must configure the Dataset's connection on the gateway in the Power BI Portal.  See [Add or Remove a Gateway Data Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-data-sources)